# While loop multiple input in one variable in C

Tags: c, char, storage, do-while

I am writing a program that suppose to receive numbers and letters and convert them to integer after storage them in one variable.

(yes, it sounds weird, but that is the activity i have to do)

As the following:

```
User = 1 -- Program receives: 49 (1 as per Ascii) - 48 (0 - Ascii) -- Output: 1

User = a -- Program receives: 97 (1 as per Ascii) - 96 (0 - Ascii) -- Output: 1 

User = B -- Program receives: 66 (B as per Ascii) - 64 (0 - Ascii) -- Output: 2
```

End of File:
Final output should be: 112 (string)

what i whant to achieve:
Final output should be: 112 (integer)

I declared the variable letters to receive the input. I set a maximum of 200 inputs.
I tried to use `scanf(" %c", &letter)` to store every input inside the variable, but in the end of the `do while` loop, i receive `"ÿ"` as output.

When i use `fgets(buchstabe, 200, stdin)` the program does not even go furthers. Does it have anything to do with the windows system?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main () {

    char letter;
    int count = 0;

    do{
        printf("Geben Sie ein Buchstabe ein: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf(" %c", &buchstabe); //here i receive the "ÿ" as output

        //fgets(buchstabe, 200, stdin); //here i have no output at all

        /*
         * this is the processing part, it convert every input according to the ASCII table.
         */
        if (buchstabe >= 48 && buchstabe <=57) {
            printf("%d\n\n", buchstabe - 48);
        }else if(toupper(buchstabe) >= 65 && toupper(buchstabe) <= 90) {
            printf("%d\n\n", toupper(buchstabe) - 64);
        }

        count++;

        //I know this EOF looks terrible, but it was the only way i could use it on windows.

    }while ((buchstabe = getchar()) != EOF);  

    printf("\n\nEingabe = %c\n", buchstabe);
    printf("Eingabe = %d\n", buchstabe);
    printf("\nContador = %d\n", count - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `buchstabe` declared anywhere.

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes, use functions `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, etc.

Comment: You're reading 2 characters each time through the loop. You read one character with `scanf()`, then another character with `getchar()`.

Comment: If you want to calclate an integer, you shouldn't be printing the result of subtracting, you should be accumulating it into an integer.

Comment: `result = result * 10 + (buchstabe - '0');`

Comment: buchstabe is letter. I just forgot to change it up. The original code is writen in german.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn-t understand how do i save the values in the variable letter.

Comment: result = result * 10 + (buchstabe - '0'); => means I dont need it in a for loo?